# Как контролировать ширину одного блока путем вычитания ширин 2 других из ширины окна

Tags: javascript, css3

Есть 3 блока. Левый, средний, правый. У левого блока `width: 25%; min-width: 150px;`. У правого блока `width: 7%; min-width: 85px;`.
Нужно вычислять ширину среднего блока из `100vw`(`document.documentElement.clientWidth`) - ширина левого блока - ширина правого блока.
Есть такой код на js, но он работает не так, как нужно...:

```
var lWidth = document.querySelector(".l-menu").offsetWidth;
var rWidth = document.querySelector(".r-menu").offsetWidth;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  window.onresize = function () {
    resize_info();
  };
});
function resize_info() {
  var mWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth - rWidth - lWidth;
  document.querySelector(".m-menu").style.width = mWidth + "px";
  console.log(document.querySelector(".m-menu").offsetWidth);
}
```

Не работает так: при увеличении экрана блок все время увеличивается, пока не займет всю ширину экрана, при уменьшении он будет уменьшаться, пока не сработает `@media`...

Comment: сам онресайз довольно "дорогой", и непонятно зачем на скрипте считать ширину ? для чего это вообще нужно ?)

Comment: @АлексДанилин: вот,я тоже голову ломаю - разве средний блок без указания ширины не распирается в боковые с чёткими размерами?

Comment: @UModeL, я вот тоже голову ломал, но он занимает ровно ту ширину, которая задается контентом. Причем эта ширина может идти вплоть до 100% ширины экрана...

Answer (score 0):

Участие JavaScript в верстке страницы - это очень плохая идея.

```
.left{
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 60vh;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fcc;
}
.right{
  width: 7%;
  min-width: 85px;
  height: 60vh;
  float:right;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #cfc;
}

.medium{
  height: 60vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #ccf;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/62pwbj7h/

Comment: Участие float в позиционировании, тоже сомнительная идея о_О

Comment: Попробуем, может получится ;)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, с чего бы вдруг? задача старее чем сам css. Поддержка браузеров float самая широкая - начиная от IE4+. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: нет, не работает, блок занимает либо ширину контента, когда присутствует display, либо занимает всю ширину экрана, без display...

Answer (score 0):

а почему бы не воспользоваться флексами?

```css
.container {
    display:            flex;
    flex-flow:          row nowrap;
    justify-content:    space-between;

    width:      50vw;
    height:     100px;
    
    border:     1px solid black;
}

.left {
    width:      25%;
    min-width:  150px;
    
    background: orange;
}

.right {
    width:      7%;
    min-width:  85px;
    
    background: lime;
}

.center {
    width:      calc(100% - 25% - 7%);
    
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "left">1</div>
  <div class = "center">2</div>
  <div class = "right">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я пробовал, но тогда почему-то ломается остальной js, который реализует прокрутку сайдбара, как у ВК...

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn: сайдбар - это один из этих трёх блоков?

Comment: @UModeL сайдбары - это левый и правый блоки. При прокрутке страницы они ведут себя обычно, как только конец/начало блока, они фиксируются.